# What is the shortcut key for generating the return data type for a statement written in Java in the Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

I was trying to apply the shortcut key to display the return data type for a statement written in Java in the Eclipse

Assume the below statement

```
driver.getTitle();
```

By applying some shortcut key I need to get the below result

```
String title = driver.getTitle();
```

Comment: See also:  with the cursor on any given line, CTRL + 1 to get various context options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

To get more options for extraction use :  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Complete list of eclipse shortcuts can be found [here](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_(3.0).pdf).

Comment: When I tried to use Alt+Shift+L then I see Extract Local Variable popup is being displayed where I am able to change driver to driver2 or some other name but the return type is not being displayed

Comment: *Return type* -- do you mean data-type?

Comment: yes the datatype. Like when I apply the shortcut key for driver.getTitle(); then the expected should be String title = driver.getTitle();

Comment: It works for me. You could try another alternative. Select the code --> right click --> Refactor --> Extract local variable. Also does `driver.getTitle();` return a String? Also now what is the data-type it is extracting to?

Comment: Got it now, when I highlight the complete statement and use the shortcut key Alt+Shift+L. Thanks for the Clarification.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows/Linux is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

For Macos is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**Alternative**

For Windows/Linux select the statement then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. From the popup menu select "Assign statement to local variable".

Comment: When I tried to use Alt+Shift+L then I see Extract Local Variable popup is being displayed where I am able to change driver to driver2 or some other name but the return type is not being displayed

Comment: @Aditya Why do you need return type for? Just put the cursor over the statement to see the result type